# NS-3, adding queue size to adhoc network

Tags: adhoc, ns-3

I would like to know if there is a way to add queue size to our adhoc network. I have a very simple case with two nodes, one sink and I would like to add queue size to both transmitter and receiver and simulate results by increasing transmission rate.

```
YansWifiPhyHelper wifiPhy =  YansWifiPhyHelper::Default ();
   YansWifiChannelHelper wifiChannel=YansWifiChannelHelper::Default();
 //  wifiChannel.SetPropagationDelay ("ns3::ConstantSpeedPropagationDelayModel");
   //wifiChannel.AddPropagationLoss ("ns3::RangePropagationLossModel", "MaxRange", DoubleValue (txpDistane));
  wifiPhy.Set ("TxPowerStart",DoubleValue (txp));
  wifiPhy.Set ("TxPowerEnd", DoubleValue (txp));
   Ptr<YansWifiChannel> channel = wifiChannel.Create ();
   wifiPhy.SetChannel (channel);
   // ns-3 supports generate a pcap trace
   wifiPhy.SetPcapDataLinkType (WifiPhyHelper::DLT_IEEE802_11);
   NqosWaveMacHelper wifi80211pMac = NqosWaveMacHelper::Default ();
   Wifi80211pHelper wifi80211p = Wifi80211pHelper::Default ();

   wifi80211p.SetRemoteStationManager ("ns3::ConstantRateWifiManager",
                                       "DataMode",StringValue (phyMode),
                                       "ControlMode",StringValue (phyMode));
   NetDeviceContainer adhocDevices = wifi80211p.Install (wifiPhy, wifi80211pMac, adhocNodes);
```